# GNU Bison: Syntax Error, unexpected <token>

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, context-free-grammar

I am writing a parser for a toy programming language using bison, but I have hit a wall:

My `grammar.y` file is the following:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "util.h"
#include "errormsg.h"

#define YYDEBUG 1

int yylex(void); /* function prototype */

void yyerror(char *s)
{
 EM_error(EM_tokPos, "%s", s);
}
%}

%union {
    int pos;
    int ival;
    string sval;
    }

%token <sval> TK_ID TK_STRING
%token <ival> TK_INT

%token <pos>           
  TK_COMMA TK_COLON TK_SEMICOLON TK_LPAREN TK_RPAREN TK_LBRACK TK_RBRACK 
  TK_LBRACE TK_RBRACE TK_DOT TK_ASSIGN
  TK_ARRAY TK_IF TK_THEN TK_ELSE TK_WHILE TK_FOR TK_TO TK_DO TK_LET TK_IN 
  TK_END TK_OF TK_BREAK TK_NIL
  TK_FUNCTION TK_VAR TK_TYPE 

/* Precedence in Bison is weird: lower is higher. Take a look at the spec too. */
%left <pos> TK_OR
%left <pos> TK_AND
%nonassoc <pos> TK_EQ TK_NEQ TK_LT TK_LE TK_GT TK_GE
%left <pos> TK_PLUS TK_MINUS
%left <pos> TK_TIMES TK_DIVIDE
%left <pos> TK_UMINUS          

%error-verbose

%start program

%%

/* According to the spec, Tiger programs are just an expression exp. */
program:    exp

/* An expression can be many things; consult the spec for more info: Expressions. */
/* For the %prec rule, take a look at 5.4 Context-Dependent Precedence on bison manual */
exp:
                lvalue
        |       TK_NIL
        |       exp exp_seq_aug
        |       TK_LPAREN TK_RPAREN
        |       TK_LET TK_IN TK_END
        |       TK_INT
        |       TK_STRING
        |       TK_MINUS exp %prec TK_UMINUS
        |       TK_ID TK_LPAREN TK_RPAREN
        |       TK_ID TK_LPAREN exp params TK_RPAREN
        |       exp TK_PLUS exp
        |       exp TK_MINUS exp
        |       exp TK_TIMES exp
        |       exp TK_DIVIDE exp
        |       exp TK_EQ exp
        |       exp TK_NEQ exp
        |       exp TK_GT exp
        |       exp TK_LT exp
        |       exp TK_GE exp
        |       exp TK_LE exp
        |       exp TK_AND exp
        |       exp TK_OR exp
        |       TK_ID TK_LBRACE TK_RBRACE
        |       TK_ID TK_LBRACE TK_ID TK_EQ exp record_exp TK_RBRACE
        |       TK_ID TK_LBRACK exp TK_RBRACK TK_OF exp
        |       lvalue TK_ASSIGN exp
        |       TK_IF exp TK_THEN exp TK_ELSE exp
        |       TK_IF exp TK_THEN exp
        |       TK_WHILE exp TK_DO exp
        |       TK_FOR TK_ID TK_ASSIGN exp TK_TO exp TK_DO exp
        |       TK_BREAK
        |       TK_LET decl_seq TK_IN exp_seq_aug TK_END
                ;

decl_seq:         
                /* empty */
        |       decl_seq decl
                ;

decl:
                type_decl
        |       var_decl
        |       func_decl
                ;

var_decl:       
                TK_VAR TK_ID TK_ASSIGN exp
        |       TK_VAR TK_ID TK_COLON TK_ID TK_ASSIGN exp
                ;

func_decl:      
                TK_FUNCTION TK_ID TK_LPAREN type_fields TK_RPAREN TK_EQ exp
        |       TK_FUNCTION TK_ID TK_LPAREN type_fields TK_COLON TK_ID TK_EQ exp
                ;

type_decl:      
                TK_TYPE TK_ID TK_EQ type
                ;

type:           
                TK_TYPE
        |       TK_LBRACE type_fields TK_RBRACE
        |       TK_ARRAY TK_OF TK_ID
                ;

type_fields:     
                /* empty */
        |       TK_ID TK_COLON TK_ID type_fields 
        |       TK_COMMA TK_ID TK_COLON TK_ID type_fields
                ;

lvalue:         
                TK_ID
        |       lvalue TK_DOT TK_ID
        |       lvalue TK_LBRACK exp TK_RBRACK
                ;       

exp_seq:      
                /* epsilon */   
        |       TK_SEMICOLON exp
        |       exp_seq TK_SEMICOLON exp
                ;      

exp_seq_aug:    
                TK_LPAREN exp_seq TK_RPAREN
                ;

params:         
                /* epsilon */
        |       params TK_COMMA exp
                ;
record_exp:     
                /* epsilon */
        |       record_exp TK_COMMA TK_ID TK_EQ exp
                ;
```

It's nothing too fancy, and gets few (96) shift/reduce conflicts (that I guess are most likely due to the if statements and the function call statements). I know it should have none to be clear, but other alternative implementations of the same exercise parse cleanly with more shift/reduce conflicts, so it shouldn't matter too much, taking into account the error message that I get too.

The token file is produced by bison from the `%token` directives (y.tab.h and y.tab.c) and the specific error message that I get is:

```
nlightnfotis@frodo ~/Software/tigerc $ ./a.out tests/test4.tig
tests/test4.tig:2.1: syntax error, unexpected TK_GE
Parsing failed
```

Which is extremely frustrating, because the parser says it found a *greater or equal* token, when the test file has none:

```
/* define a recursive function */
let

/* calculate n! */
function nfactor(n: int): int =
                if  n = 0
                        then 1
                        else n * nfactor(n-1)

in
        nfactor(10)
end
```

How can I possibly debug this?

**[EDIT]**: Here's the source code for my `flex` lexer, as requested:

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include "util.h"
#include "tokens.h"
#include "errormsg.h"

int charPos = 1;

int 
yywrap (void)
{
  charPos = 1;
  return 1;
}

// Adjust the token position in the string
// Mainly used for error checking
void 
adjust (void)
{
  EM_tokPos = charPos;
  charPos  += yyleng;
}

%}

/* Will be used for conditional activation of the comment rule. */
%x C_COMMENT

digits [0-9]+
letters [_a-zA-Z]+


%%
" "  {adjust(); continue;}
\n   {adjust(); EM_newline(); continue;}
\t       {adjust(); continue;}

"/*"              {adjust(); BEGIN(C_COMMENT);}
<C_COMMENT>[^*\n] {adjust();}
<C_COMMENT>"*/"   {adjust(); BEGIN(INITIAL);}

\"(\\.|[^"])*\" {adjust(); yylval.sval = String(yytext); return STRING;}

","  {adjust(); return COMMA;}
";"      {adjust(); return SEMICOLON;}
":"      {adjust(); return COLON;}
"."      {adjust(); return DOT;}
"+"      {adjust(); return PLUS;}
"-"      {adjust(); return MINUS;}
"*"      {adjust(); return TIMES;}
"/"      {adjust(); return DIVIDE;}
"="      {adjust(); return EQ;}
"<>"     {adjust(); return NEQ;}
"<"      {adjust(); return LT;}
"<="     {adjust(); return LE;}
">"      {adjust(); return GT;}
">="     {adjust(); return GE;}
"&"      {adjust(); return AND;}
"|"      {adjust(); return OR;}
":="     {adjust(); return ASSIGN;}
"("      {adjust(); return LPAREN;}
")"      {adjust(); return RPAREN;}
"{"      {adjust(); return LBRACE;}
"}"      {adjust(); return RBRACE;}
"["      {adjust(); return LBRACK;}
"]"      {adjust(); return RBRACK;}

for      {adjust(); return FOR;}
if       {adjust(); return IF;}
then     {adjust(); return THEN;}
else     {adjust(); return ELSE;}
while    {adjust(); return WHILE;}
to       {adjust(); return TO;}
do       {adjust(); return DO;}
let      {adjust(); return LET;}
in       {adjust(); return IN;}
end      {adjust(); return END;}
of       {adjust(); return OF;}
break    {adjust(); return BREAK;}
nil      {adjust(); return NIL;}
function {adjust(); return FUNCTION;}
var      {adjust(); return VAR;}
type     {adjust(); return TYPE;}
array    {adjust(); return ARRAY;}

{digits}           {adjust(); yylval.ival  = atoi (yytext); return INT;}
{letters}[a-zA-Z0-9_]* {adjust(); yylval.sval = String (yytext); return ID;}

.                  {adjust(); EM_error (EM_tokPos,"illegal token");}
```

Comment: Where is your lexer?

Comment: @codenheim just updated the question to also contain the lexer code.

Comment: Ok, I'm answering. In short your lexer isn't returning the actual tokens defined by bison token directives.

Comment: @codenheim How so? Isn't it (it being bison) supposed to call `yylex()` and get the tokens from there? Is it that the `%token` directives in the bison file are playing a nasty trick to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
How can I possibly debug this?
```

For starters, you need to learn to use the Bison debug options. That will output a dump of all the states, and granted, it takes a lot of patience and time to get comfortable debugging them, at first look you can often at least narrow down the rule that is causing the issue.

As far as your problem, your lexer isn't returning the tokens defined by bison.

In Bison you have `%token TK_GE` for example, yet your lexer returns `GE`. Bison grammar only knows about TK_GE and that is what it expects. It'll define tokens as incrementing sequence of numbers above the ASCII sequence if I recall, and you have to use those values in your lexer.

Unless you are doing some sort of redefinition that I can't see in tokens.h, you need to rewrite lexer to do:

```
">="     {adjust(); return TK_GE;}
```

Likely you have `#define GE 42` somewhere, yet bison is producing a token file with `#define TK_GE 21` (example values).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check it out now, and get back to you as soon as I am done with it.

Comment: Keep in mind, your lexer and parser have to share token definition. It is just C

Comment: Huge thanks! While I still get syntax errors, this time it's because of my grammar, and not some incomprehensible error message! You helped me get past the brick wall! For the record all I had to do, was change the tokens returned from the lexer to be prefixed with `TK_` and change the token definition file from my custom one (`tokens.h`) to the one produced by bison (`y.tab.h`)

Comment: No problem. In the end, tokens are just integers. So you could return 1, 2, 3, 256, 257, 258, etc. and Bison would work, but in order for your lexer and parser to agree on the definition of a token, you use the symbolic definition, which is a #define constant. In the future, if you were to rewrite your parser by hand, you could still reuse those token definitions, though you would need to maintain the token file directly.